# Can't find the join cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am trying to find the join cumulative distribution function of $X$ and $Y$ defined as

$$X = \min(\tau_1, \tau)$$
$$Y = \min(\tau_2, \tau)$$

$\tau$, $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are random variables with exponential distribution of parameters $\lambda$, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

I solved like this

$$F(s,t) = P(X \leq s \land Y \leq t) = P(\min(\tau_1, \tau) \leq s \land \min(\tau_2,\tau) \leq t) = P((\tau_1\leq s \lor \tau \leq s) \land (\tau_2\leq t \lor \tau \leq t)) = \ldots$$

Please, can you give me a hint on how to go on? I got stucked.

Comment: $X\leq$ s and $Y \leq t$ are *not* independent events, as they are both influenced by $\tau$.  One being true makes the other more likely so there is a positive correlation

Comment: *Hint.* It is easier to look at the survival function: $P(X>s,Y>t)=P(\tau>\max(s,t),\,\tau_1>s,\,\tau_2>t)$.

Comment: I could solve easily $P(X>s \land Y>t)$, but if I use De Morgan law, I get $P(X\leq s \land Y \leq t) = 1-P(X>s \lor Y>t)$

Answer (score 1):

The solution is
$$F(s,t) = P(X\leq s \land Y \leq t) = 1 - P(X > s \lor Y > t) =$$
$$= 1 - \left[P(X>s) + P(Y>t) - P(X > s \land Y > t)\right] =$$
$$ =1 - \left( e^{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda )s} + e^{-(\lambda_2 + \lambda )t} -  e^{-\lambda_1 s - \lambda_2 t - \lambda \max(s,t)}\right) = 1 - e^{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda )s} - e^{-(\lambda_2 + \lambda )t} +  e^{-\lambda_1 s - \lambda_2 t - \lambda \max(s,t)}$$